# Top nav bar broken in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a Top nav bar working in major browsers, including ie8 and above. HOWEVER. When I put IE8 into compatibility mode ( which I thought would test for ie7 browsers) it no longer works. i can find any logical reason why it doesn't. here's the site: http://redemptionconnect.com/pages/articles#

Can anyone help with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out! All I had to do was apply float: left; to the li element. That worked in ie7!

Answer (score 0):

The logical reason is that older browsers have various problems (not just IE, but often times older IE can be a huge problem).

IE7 doesn't support inline-block.  You're going to have to figure out a different solution.

Start here, it may help you.

http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html

Comment: I followed those examples, but now it breaks in chrome! :p

Comment: What I don't get is that Google has it working, and I've tried using the same CSS they have. But I just can't seem to get it to work the same.